# How can I delete generated test results in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, mstest

When i am trying to delete sonar Mstest results in jenkins pipeline I am not able to delete  those results folder and Jenkins is running on windows slave node could you please help me with that.

Comment: To help you more details will be required. Where are those results? Which plugin are you using, what error do you get, ...?

Comment: have you tried `sh "rm -rf /locationOfFiles"` ??

Answer (score 1):

Before the tests execute in your pipeline you can remove the previous test results like so:

```
dir('directoryToDelete') {
    deleteDir()
}
```

directoryToDelete is WORKSPACE relative.